# SQL query with c# stringbuilder error near "=" symbol

Tags: c#, sql-server, runtime-error

I'm working on some code that creates procedures with C#. When I try to run my code:

```
StringBuilder sbSP1 = new StringBuilder();

sbSP1.AppendLine("CREATE PROCEDURE " + ProcN + "DELETE @id int=0 AS BEGIN DELETE FROM " + tname + " WHERE " + PK + " = @id END");

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sbSP1.ToString(), connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

This part *doesn't work*. It throws an exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

But when I try to run this part:

```
StringBuilder sbSP3 = new StringBuilder();
sbSP3.AppendLine("CREATE PROCEDURE " + ProcN + "GET AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT " + columns + " from " + tname + "  END");

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sbSP3.ToString(), connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

it runs correctly.

Where is my mistake in the first snippet of code?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the resultant query text. The problem ought to be quite obvious then.

Comment: @Afonso... uh... even for queries to create stored procedures? I don't think that would work very well.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `sbSP1.ToString()`?

Comment: @Babbillumpa I asked the same thing, but deleted my comment after realising the OP wants a stored procedure with a name of `[...]DELETE` with a parameter `@id int` with a default value of zero. It's not the keyword `DELETE`.

Comment: @john Why not? Assuming that the vars used to create the procedure come from some kind of input you should use SQLParameters.

Comment: @Afonso SQL Server doesn't support anything like that. You can't do `CREATE PROCEDURE @ProcName AS ...`, you'll just get a syntax error.

Comment: Why are you creating procedures at runtime? this is a design time operation.

Comment: OT Why are you using a StringBuilder here? You are adding just a single string that you concatenated yourself. StringBuilder is just overhead here, use a plain String

Comment: I'd really recommend doing as @mjwills suggested and including the exact value of `sbSP1.ToString()` at the time you assign it to the `SqlCommand`, but my initial hunch was that `ProcN` or `PK` contained a space, or some invalid character.

Comment: @mjwills thanks. when i checked exact value of sbSP1.ToString() to be sure, i realized some of earlier procedures changes PK to something else. I think its the problem. Im trying to correct that now.

Comment: You still haven't updated the question with the value. If you don't plan to update that, please delete the question since we can't help without it.

Answer (score 4):

Without `sbSP1` *final text* it's difficult to pin down the error; as a *working hypothesis* I suggest that `PK` being complex (e.g. `"id value"`) 
should be *escaped* - `[PK]`. In order to avoid such kind of errors, please, never *build* the query, but make *procedure's text* being *readable* with a help of *string interpolation* - `$` and *verbatim strings* - `@`.

```
 //TODO: check the text, is it the procedure you want to create?
 string text = 
   $@"create procedure [{ProcN}Delete] 
        @id int = 0 as 
      begin
        delete
          from [{tname}]
         where [{PK}] = @id 
      end;"; 

 //DONE: do not close connection manually, but wrap it into using
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
   connection.Open();

   using (qlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, connection)) {
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }  
 }
```